# Snapback in Firefox

Tags: ubuntu, firefox, browser-addons, plugins

In my address bar, on the left of the star, there is an option Snapback: [Empty] for every site. I haven't seen this before and I don't have the Snapback plugin. Doesn't anyone know where it may have come from and what it does?

I recently upgraded to 3.5.6 on Ubuntu, and may have had some plugins upgraded, but not sure which. I have a ridiculous number of plugins on this comp otherwise I could just try disabling them one at a time.

Comment: Is it always there or just on certain sites? If it always there, please check your installed AddOns.

Comment: I checked my addons - not there

Answer (score 1):

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1245

> SnapBack similar to Apple's Safari. Save an URL as "waypoint". Follow as many links as you want and then jump...

It seems some other people have had it automatically installed, if you upgrade to 3.5 then it will go away